# Meteor: How to get account password reset token only, no email

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am looking to use a sendgrid template to send the account password reset email.

So basically instead of using the function `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` I need the function `Accounts.getResetPasswordURL`

Which will give me a password reset URL which I can use to send over to sendgrid which will be used in a template.

So how can I do this? How can I use Meteor to just get the password reset URL but not actually send the email? I will send the email with the URL manually using a API call to sendgrid.

Comment: same goes for the verify email. I would like to send that through sendgrid too. So I need a function to get the URL for a specific user and I will pass that URL to sendgrid template.

Comment: Are you using some kind of package to send emails through sendgrid? I'd like to take a look at it to see what kind of features it has.

Comment: I am looking to use meteor's built in system, I just dont want meteor to send the actual email, and I just want to get the link meteor would have sent in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I haven't used sendgrid, so I'm going by the [API over here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/).*

First off, you want to configure Meteor to use [Sendgrid's SMTP servers](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200328026-Recommended-SMTP-settings). This way, you can send e-mails straight through Meteor:

```js
Meteor.startup(function(){
    process.env.MAIL_URL = "smtp://" + sendgridUsername + ":" + sendgridPasswordOrAPIkey + "@smtp.sendgrid.net:465";
});
```

You can change the default template for the reset e-mail. This can be done by modifying [`Accounts.emailTemplates`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_emailtemplates):

```js
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html = function(user, url){
    // url contains the reset url! :)
    var result;
    var sendgridTemplateId = ''; // Set this to the template id you're using in sendgrid
    try {
        // Get sendgrid template
        // API link: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/templates.html
        result = HTTP.get("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates/" + sendgridTemplateId);
        result = result.data.templates[0].versions[0].html_content;
        // then insert URL to the template
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while fetching sendgrid template!', error);
        return false;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Now when you use [`Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendresetpasswordemail) the above template will be used, which actually just fetches the sendgrid template and returns that!

Comment: @nearpoint Also, I looked into it and I don't think sendgrid allows you to pass in variables when fetching the template. So you have to replace the url in the HTML content yourself or if you know of a better way to get the template (and pass in the url), please let me know, so I can update the answer. Most other services allow you to pass in variables when fetching templates, so it's usually simpler (I use this method in my own application as well).

Comment: you are correct! I asked sendgrid and you cannot pass in a variable. But they do leave in the substitution variable like `--URL--` So I can parse the content myself easily and replace the --URL-- with the real URL using the replace method.

Comment: @nearpoint Also, in my own app, I implemented a simple cache for this approach. Usually, e-mail templates don't get changed too often, but `HTTP.get()` can create some overhead if you've got a lot of users. So caching the response for a while is sensible. Sendgrid has an SMTP API which maybe could be used instead, but for that you'd have to dig in the `email` package a little bit to see if it's implementable. I don't have the time for that right now, but it's an idea worth exploring.

Comment: ah yes this is a good idea. I should cache the template in the database or something. Maybe create a button in the admin interface to refetch the template manually whenever I click it.

Comment: @nearpoint If you're lazy and don't have too many templates, you can just use a variable (object with template ids as keys and html content as values) in Javascript to cache them in memory. Should be a lot easier to implement. If you've got a lot of templates, then it might hog too much memory and caching them in DB would definitely be better. If sendgrid has webhooks, you could even make the cache update only when a template actually gets changed. Just ideas for you :P

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible with the way the procedure is performed at the moment.

The `accounts-password` package generates a random token and sends the email in the `sendResetPasswordEmail()` method.

You can either fork the package, generate your own token the way it is done [in the original method](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L603), or change the behavior of the [email](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email) package to handle email on your own.